# Strictly increasing approximation of the identiy

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Is there always a strictly increasing approximation of the identity in a separable $C^*$-algebra?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Let $(e_n)$ be an increasing approximate identity with $e_1$ strictly positive and consider $(a_ne_n)$ where $(a_n)$ is any sequence of positive reals that strictly increases to $1$.